# Fitbit account Integration in Android

Tags: android, callback, fitbit

I am working on an application which is related to medical science, where I have to implement FitBit device with my application.

I am following FitBit developer tools for it but I am unable to  integrate it and if I am doing it manually without FitBit library I am unable to back on my application after authentication.

My code is below-

```
    private void login() {

            try {

                HttpResponse response = null;
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                        "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=7af733f021f649bcac32f6f7a4fe2e9a&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1358921319&oauth_nonce=456236281&oauth_callback=http://www.androidhub4you.com/&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=5cefb18d2a80073520211f03f8d75321&oauth_signature=QdVUzMvT6tveGyoPu%2BEevzvo07s%3D");
                response = client.execute(request);

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String webServiceInfo = "";
                while ((webServiceInfo = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("****Step 1***", "Webservice: " + webServiceInfo);
                    authToken = webServiceInfo.substring(12, 44);
                    Log.e("Auth token:", "Webservice: " + authToken);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

And after getting authToken I open a web page but I am unable to back
 on my application again.

```
      private void openURL() {
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
                        + authToken + "&display=touch");
            }
```

Comment: This below link has sample code with fitbit framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393507/fitbit-framework-is-available/34393522#34393522

Comment: I also faced similar problem when I have started working with fitbit authentication. I got a sample project from which I upgraded the whole process to nougat compatibility. You may follow my github project https://github.com/Asad-noor/FitbitTestApi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got answer of my own question-

```
try {

            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                    "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=7af733f021f649bcac32f6f7a4fe2e9a&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1358921319&oauth_nonce=456236281&oauth_callback=http://www.androidhub4you.com/&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=5cefb18d2a80073520211f03f8d75321&oauth_signature=QdVUzMvT6tveGyoPu%2BEevzvo07s%3D");
            response = client.execute(request);

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String webServiceInfo = "";
            while ((webServiceInfo = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("****Step 1***", "Webservice: " + webServiceInfo);
                authToken = webServiceInfo.substring(12, 44);
                Log.e("Auth token:", "Webservice: " + authToken);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And after that-

```
    String fitUrl = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
                    + authToken +"&display=touch";
            webView.loadUrl(fitUrl);
 Intent intent = new Intent(FitBitActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            pActivity.finishChildActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:**
You can check full code here on my blog-

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/11/fitbit-integration-in-android-login.html

Also, you can download zip code from my github account-
https://github.com/manishsri01/FitbitIntegration

Comment: Did you manage to automatize the whole process? How do you access generated PIN after user login?

Comment: @M.V. After login I read URL response and sub-string it.

authToken = webServiceInfo.substring(12, 44);
Log.e("Auth token:", "Webservice: " + authToken);

Comment: Sure ... By that you get token ... So you can call FitBit login page and authorization.. after that you should receive verifier and than request access token... When I do that.. All I get on screen is PIN and I don'y want user to copy/paste PIN :)

Comment: Regarding this: https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API#OAuthAuthenticationintheFitbitAPI-TheOAuthFlow The problem for me is on point D... by loading data I get user login (FitBit side) ...

Comment: @ManishSrivastava: Please make a tutorial on "Integrating Android with Fitbit". You can also do it the Stackoverflow's question'n'answer fashion.

Comment: @AnasAzeem is it demanded on stackoverflow? i have did it in one of my application. if needed i can post whole code here.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava: That would be great. With some explanation please.

Comment: @AnasAzeem please download zip code..and if it help you please give up vote to my answer and question.

Comment: @M.V. please download zip code..and if it help you please give up vote to my answer and question.

Comment: Hi... Code is helpful, but it doesn't solve the main problem for me ... How do you calculate oauth_signature? It is hardcoded... QdVUzMvT6tveGyoPu%2BEevzvo07s%3D

Comment: @M.V. follow fitbit developer link and follow step by step and oauth_signature is also there. nothing hard coded..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava I have a prupose for you ... Inside WebViewClient I overrode the openCallbackURL and by that I avoided showing the redrect site... I do checking if url to redirect is proper I do not redirect.. so in onPageFinished I only have code to dismiss progress bar...

Comment: @M.V. great, thanks for sharing your idea. i will edit my code in my application.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava Hi ... me again :) Did you notice changes in FitBit ... did you by any chance found solution for that problem? I can not get over getting access_token after changes on January 13th..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava :it throws error "No authorization header has been provided in the request". with user_id= null .plz have a look ..

Comment: "Android applications may use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of app switching to the default browser. Use of WebView is prohibited." https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

I used this and various other sources to create a sample "connecting to Fitbit from Android" project using the Scribe OAuth library. Project is [here](https://github.com/pugwonk/FitbitAndroidSample) on GitHub. It's something of a work in progress but I do have it authenticating and getting some data back for the appropriate user.